# Stripe.js payment not work php laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe.js in my Laravel project 5.6 but when I checked out I do not see the value of the item registered in the Stripe dashboard. I do not know what error I may have, please I need your help.

Code PHP:

```
public function postCheckout(Request $request) {
    if(!Session::has('cart')) {
        return redirect()->route('shop.shoopingCart');
    }
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    Stripe::setApiKey('pk_test_H7JdFZrdbUPYredN7cIG3woA');
    try {
        $charge = Charge::create(array(
           "amount" => $cart->totalPrice * 100,
           "currency" => "usd",
           "source" => $request->input('stripeToken'), // obtained with Stripe.js
           "description" => "Test Charge"
        ));
        $order = new Order();
        $order->cart = serialize($cart);
        $order->address = $request->input('address');
        $order->name = $request->input('name');
        $order->payment_id = $charge->id;
        Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('checkout')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }
    Session::forget('cart');
    return redirect()->route('product.index')->with('success', 'Successfully purchased products!');
}
```

Code JavaScript:

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_H7JdFZrdbUPYredN7cIG3woA');
var $form = $('#checkout-form');
$form.submit(function(event){
$('#charge-error').addClass('hidden');
$form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
Stripe.card.createdToken({
    number: $('#card-number').val(),
    cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
    exp_month: $('#card-exp-month').val(),
    exp_year: $('#card-exp-year').val(),
    name: $('#card-name').val(),
}, stripeResponseHandler);
return false;
});
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
if(response.error) {
    $('#charge-error').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#charge-error').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
}
else {
    var token = response.id;
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden"name="stripeToken"/>').val(token));

    $form.get(0).submit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a try because setTimeout is working fine for me.

```
         setTimeout(function(){ 
            // Request a token from Stripe:
            Stripe.card.createdToken({
              number: $('#card-number').val(),
              cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
              exp_month: $('#card-exp-month').val(),
              exp_year: $('#card-exp-year').val(),
              name: $('#card-name').val(),
            }, stripeResponseHandler);
         }, 500);
```